# Stuck at tracking a SIGFPE/Arithmetic exception

Tags: c++, assembly, gdb

I'm trying to debug a `SIGFPE` signal that is raised inside a library that I don't have it's source code. I'm using gdb and the asm layout to see what is going on.

These are the instructions before the exception:

```
   0xcd3fffa <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+830>     fstpl  -0x68(%ebp)                                    
B+ 0xcd3fffd <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+833>     fldl   -0x58(%ebp)                                    
   0xcd40000 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+836>     fstpl  0x4(%esp)                                      
   0xcd40004 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+840>     mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax                                 
   0xcd40007 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+843>     mov    %eax,(%esp)                                    
  >0xcd4000a <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+846>     call   0xcd408c0 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1AnotherMethodNameEd>   
   0xcd4000f <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1MethodNameEdddd+851>     mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
```

When I type `ni` to go from the instruction at `0xcd4000a` to the one at `0xcd4000f` I get the following error

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x0cd408e8 in name_space::ClassName::AnotherMethodName(double) () at /Path/to/ClassName.h:69
```

I am not familiar with assembly but I was expecting the instrcution pointer to be `0xcd408c0` where the instructions for `AnotherMethodName` start. But the instruction pointer has jumped to `0xcd408e8` address. Which is still inside `AnotherMethodName()` method.

```
    0xcd408e4 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1AnotherMethodNameEd+36> fldz                                                          
    0xcd408e6 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1AnotherMethodNameEd+38> fdivrp %st,%st(1)                                             
   >0xcd408e8 <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1AnotherMethodNameEd+40> fldz                                                          
    0xcd408ea <_ZN8name_space11ClassName1AnotherMethodNameEd+42> fucomip %st(1),%st
```

After the instruction at `0xcd408e8` it jumps to my exception handler.

I have searched a lot to even get to this point. But at the moment I have no clue how I should continue.

I have also checked the floating point registers and they don't seem to contain any weird values.

What is raising this exception?

Comment: Typing `ni` at the point of a function call will run the function and stop when it returns (it may stop before that, if a breakpoint or exception are hit). There's a different command, `stepi`, which will run exactly one instruction, even if it's a function call.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, Mark. You are right. After posting this I realized I had to use `stepi` or `si` to run just one single instruction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot be `fldz` since it just sets a register to 0

The exception occurred at `fdivrp %st,%st(1)`

You said you checked "wierd" values. But above must be a division by zero. Did you check st for zero too? must be zero. No weird, just zero.

FDIVRP ST(i), ST(0)     Divide ST(0) by ST(i), store result in ST(i), and pop the register stack

Edit: not sure of what's happening there. Check the parameters you're calling your third party software with. You may have passed some zero value for say, number of items, maybe because of uninitialized variables which the library does not like.
(sorry for all the guesswork!)

Comment: Yes, you are right. `fldz` at `0xcd408e4` sets `st(0)` to zero. Then `fdivrp %st,%st(1)` divides `st(1)` by `st(0)`. It is indeed a division by zero! But I get the exception after `fldz` at `0xcd408e8`. Do you know why?

Comment: Not sure, but the PC may already have went through the instruction before it detects ZERODIV.